# Not able to set variable in c-shell

Tags: shell, scripting

In the following line of code for C-shell:
set signame = `echo "te.add[2:0] 100 1000 0 10"  | sed 's/\ /\n/g' | sed -n '1p'`

I wrote the right-hand side in backquotes. But when I run it I get the error:
set: No match.
How can I remove this error?

Comment: You should change the title to "Not able to do anything useful in c-shell".  Seriously, the solution to problems in csh is to stop using csh.

Answer (score 0):

```
% set signame = `echo "te.add[2:0] 100 1000 0 10"  | sed 's/\ /\n/g' | sed -n '1p'`

% echo "$signame"

te.add[2:0]
```

Use the one below "~" character to include the commands.